# Android emulator giving error while opening in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-emulator

while opening virtual emulator i am getting error

INFO | Android emulator version 33.1.24.0 (build_id 11237101) (CL:N/A) INFO | Found systemPath C:\Users\paritosh\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-30\google_apis_playstore\x86\ WARNING | Please update the emulator to one that supports the feature(s): Vulkan INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 8e4:8032:2802:0:e0ca:8032:2802:0 (2x) ERROR | Running multiple emulators with the same AVD ERROR | is an experimental feature. ERROR | Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature. INFO | Storing crashdata in: , detection is enabled for process: 11180 INFO | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each individual line launch with the -log-nofilter flag. INFO | IPv4 server found: INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: e0ca:8032:2802:0:e0ca:8032:2802:0 INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: e0ca:8032:2802:0:e0ca:8032:2802:0 (2x) INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 58d6:8032:2802:0:e0ca:8032:2802:0 INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 58d6:8032:2802:0:e0ca:8032:2802:0 (2x) INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 8e4:8032:2802:0:e0ca:8032:2802:0

i tried deleting virtual emulator, but it is not working , earlier when i was using the previous version of Android Studio it was working , BUt when i updated to the latest version i am getting this error.